# How to force Vimeo player to play inline using UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, vimeo

I am using following code to display Vimeo player in UIWebView:

```
_webView.delegate = self;
_webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;    
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/12536488"]]];
```

Now when I'm clicking play button, native iPhone movie player appears.

**How to enable inline playback?**

What I already was trying to do is to get acces to *video* element after page is loaded to set *webkit-playsinline* attribute. I wrote:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];"];
}
```

But *video* variable appears to be undefined.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You're on exactly the right track, but unfortunately it's impossible to change the video tag within the iframe. Unless there's a work-around I'm not aware of it's up to Vimeo to add a parameter to their JS. I'd suggest contacting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all we decided to use paid account. Vimeo provides direct links for videos stored on "Pro" accounts.