# Can I play a vimeo video in a UIWebView inline (not fullscreen)?

Tags: iphone, vimeo

I have looked many more forums and blogs to do this but still now not found any answer to do this.Is it possible to play a Vimeo video in a UIWebView on an iPhone inline.In their forum they mention it is not possible , but in the official Vimeo iOS app they allowed to play the video inline in iPhone

I have set allowsInlineMediaPlayback to YES, but still it plays fullscreen.It works fine for youtube and mp4 video but not for Vimeo videos

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258833/how-to-force-vimeo-player-to-play-inline-using-uiwebview) might help you.
your video needs to have a webkit-playsinline attribute. Below text is from Apple docs: "In order for video to play inline, not only does this property need to be set on the view, but the video element in the HTML document must also include the webkit-playsinline attribute."